# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phone_verify.views'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, twilio, sms

I am using django-phone-verify in my drf project to send otp and phone call for sign in.
When i want to import start_verification from phone_verify.views this error is showing"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'phone_verify.views"

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from phone_verify.views import start_verification

@api_view(['POST'])
def sign_in_sms(request):
    phone_number = request.data.get('phone_number')
    if not phone_number:
        return Response({'error': 'Phone number is required'}, status=400)

    start_verification(phone_number, method='sms')

    return Response({'success': 'Verification started'})

@api_view(['POST'])
def sign_in_phone_call(request):
    phone_number = request.data.get('phone_number')
    if not phone_number:
        return Response({'error': 'Phone number is required'}, status=400)

    start_verification(phone_number, method='call')

    return Response({'success': 'Verification started'})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from phone_verify.urls import urlpatterns as phone_verify_urls
from django.urls import path
from sms.views import sign_in_sms, sign_in_phone_call


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('sms.urls')),
    path('phone-verify/', include(phone_verify_urls)),
    path('sign-in/sms/', sign_in_sms),
    path('sign-in/phone-call/', sign_in_phone_call),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'phone_verify',
    'sms',
]

PHONE_VERIFICATION = {
    'FROM_NUMBER': 'my number',
    'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID': 'my sid',
    'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN': 'my token',
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of `from phone_verify.views import start_verification`? is it a view?

Comment: Cannot find views.py file in phone_verify

Answer (score 0):

As I see, there is no method or views named `start_verification`. Either you are looking for another package or you are looking at an outdated document. Hence, if you want to integrate [`django-phone-verify`](https://github.com/CuriousLearner/django-phone-verify) package, then you need to follow their [documentation](https://www.sanyamkhurana.com/django-phone-verify/usage.html). According to their documentation, you can integrate the API endpoints like this:

```
# In urls.py

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from phone_verify.api import VerificationViewSet

default_router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
default_router.register('phone', VerificationViewSet, basename='phone')

urlpatterns = default_router.urls
```

FYI: Twilo has [a blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verify-phone-numbers-django-twilio-verify) about how to send verification SMS to integrate with Django.